# How to fetch files from a directory based on condition

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking to fetch specific files from a directory based on their creation date. I want ".jpeg" files that their creation dates are more than 30 days before now to be fetched. how do we go about? I've written the code but I'm stuck in 'Where' clause

```
FileInfo[] fi;
DirectoryInfo di= new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\src_folder");

fi = di.GetFiles("*.jpeg").Where(....
```

Now here in 'Where' clause I'm not sure how do I go ahead for fetching files which are existed more than 30 days.

Comment: I think that you should make it clear that what do you mean "more than 30 days"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can be helpful:

```
FileInfo[] fi;
DirectoryInfo di= new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\src_folder");

DateTime beginning = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-30);
fi = di.GetFiles("*.jpeg")
       .Where(file => file.CreationTimeUtc < beginning)
       .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`GetFiles` returns an array of `FileInfo`. Each of the elements will have `CreationTimeUtc` property you can use for to filter only items older than 30 days:

```
var limit = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-30);
fi = di.GetFiles("*.jpeg").Where(f => f.CreationTimeUtc < limit).ToList();
```

It you want file that were modified earlier than 30 days ago use `LastWriteTimeUtc` instead of `CreationTimeUtc`.

Comment: Your solution wouldn't work if system time/date settings changed between when the file was created and when the code is executed.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DateTime from_dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
DateTime to_dt = DateTime.Now;

var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\src_folder");

var files = dir.GetFiles("*.jpeg")
  .Where(file=>file.LastWriteTime >= from_dt && file.LastWriteTime <= to_dt);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got your question, you want files that were created above 30 days ago? If yes:

```
   fi = di.GetFiles("*.jpeg").Where(file => file.CreationTimeUtc < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-30)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.